# How to insert code in stack overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I did the following: I wrote my question, paste my code, then click {} from the format toolbar. My code turns to grey-colored, but is not colored as I saw in some other posts (keywords are colored) also I can't insert spaces once I use {}. how can I format my code in my posts ?

Comment: You will get the proper colors once you add the correct language tag to the question.

Comment: @BoPersson: there is a delay even if the correct tags are present. Only if you do not make changes and wait a moment does the syntax highlighting kick in.

Comment: This delay is almost 5 seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of How do I format my code blocks? - flagged ( hehe in the same time Yanis ;) )

Comment: @Bo Persson: that is it.

Comment: If you'd probably tag your questions (with e.g. java), the syntax highlighting would work.

Comment: how do you insert code in comments? I tried to use ctrl + k - but that isn't working

Answer (score 5):

Wait a moment. When editing your question or answer, the syntax highlighting is disabled temporarily. If you *stop* editing, after a timeout the highlighting will kick in and the colours will appear. The delay is around 5 seconds, I believe.

This *does* depend on the tags present on the question, or you can add hints in the markdown source of your post.

To add hints, simply add a `<!-- language: ... -->` comment on a line of it's own (*not* indented) before the code block. If you use `language-all` instead, the choice is applied to *all* code blocks in your post. See the [site help text on this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).